# How to make Arduino toggle a variable after a completion of UART transmission?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, uart, usart, isr

I would like to have a bit of code executed (like toggling a flag variable),
after a completion of UART transmission issued by Serial.write(buf, len).

I tried several things to no success. Could someone suggest what would be the best way?

Thanks.
m

Answer (score 0):

According to the code on the Arduino repository (you can see it [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino), particularly the `HardwareSerial`, `Stream` and `Print` classes) the `Serial` class functions are not blocking: they use an internal buffer which is emptied by the ISR.

Looking at the code, you have two possibilities.

The first and easiest one is to use the built-in [`Serial.flush`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) function. This function waits for the uC to complete the sending and returns only when everything has been sent.

The second way is to mimic the flush behavior; this is what you need if you don't want the program to stop (i.e. perform other tasks) and just check if the board is sending data or not. If bit UDRIE0 (register UCSR0B) is set then the library has some data in its queue. At the end, however, you have to wait for the final byte to be sent, so you also have to check that bit TXC0(register UCSR0A) is cleared.

To implement and test this, I wrote this simple program:

```
unsigned long thisMillis = -1;
unsigned long lastMillis = -1;
char mybuffer[256];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
bool isSending()
{
  return bit_is_set(UCSR0B, UDRIE0) || bit_is_clear(UCSR0A, TXC0);
}
void loop() {
  int printed = snprintf(mybuffer, 256, "time: %lu\r\n", millis());
  Serial.write(mybuffer, printed);
  // Just enable ONE of the following methods
  //Serial.flush();
  //while(isSending());
  lastMillis = millis();
}
```

Then I simulated it.

When neither the flush nor the while are enabled, the board buffers the string until it can. Then, when the buffer becomes full, starts waiting for some chars to go away before filling it again. Consequently we will see a lot of strings in the first milliseconds, then almost equally spaced strings (when the buffer is full). And in fact the output of the program is this one:

```
time: 0
time: 0
time: 1
time: 1
time: 1
time: 1
time: 2
time: 2
time: 7
time: 17
time: 27
```

When, however, we uncomment the Serial.flush function, the loop will wait for all the data to get out of the uC before looping again. This leads to equally spaced timestamps just from the beginning, and in fact this is the output

```
time: 0
time: 9
time: 19
time: 29
time: 39
time: 51
```

When enabling the while loop the behavior is exactly the same:

```
time: 0
time: 9
time: 19
time: 29
time: 39
time: 51
```

So, summing up: if you want to wait for the board to send just go with `Serial.flush()`; if you want to just test it (and then do something else) test the two bits reported above.

Comment: Many thanks frarugi!
I used the technicque you described (checking the UDRIE0), but without the TXC0 part - thanks for pointing that out.
Still, I wondered if I could have that ISR that pushes the bytes thru USART, to trigger a timer for example, when it doesn't have any more data to deal with... That way the main code and the 'multitasking' would get more elegant and efficient (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Well, if you don't check the TXC0 bit you won't wait for all the data to be sent, since the last byte is still in transmission. As for what you are asking, it COULD have some advantages, but I think they are very limited. If you really need it to fire something at the very moment the transmission ends you can take the source code for the HardwareSerial (see the link to retrieve it, or in your arduino folder) and modify it (you can just rename it and then modify the ISR only, leaving all the rest of the code unchanged). That's the power of open source! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

 _SFR_BYTE(UCSR0B) |= _BV(TXCIE0);        //Enable TXCIE0 interrupts

Serial.print("When UART finishes to send this text, it will call the routine ISR(USART0_TX_vect) ");

}


void loop() {


}

  ISR(USART1_TX_vect)
{
//do whatever you want, but as quick as you can.

}
```